# GPerfTools/pprof: what does a dashed line mean?

Tags: linux, profiling, gperftools

When you use the "--gv" option in GPerfTool's pprof command, you get a very pretty graph. Yay.

Lines are either thick, thin, dashed or solid. I figure thick/thin is based on the number of sample entries that follow that line.

But I have neither figure out nor found documentation as to what the dashed line means. Am currently going thru the pprof CODE, but frankly that's a REALLY STUPID way to figure out what it means. Thus, in addition to answering what the dashed line means, can you please point out some document that gives a legend of the pprof gv format?

[This one (http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/cpu_profiler.html) must be out of date](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/cpu_profiler.html), as it has no mention of the dashed format...leading me to worry that it might be QUITE out of date.

Answer (score 2):

From the code, it APPEARS that a dashed line means an inline function call. However, confirmation would be good.

DOCUMENTATION would be even better!

```
  if ($x[1] =~ m/\(inline\)/) {
    $style .= ",dashed";
  }
```

[source](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/pprof)

Answer (score 0):

The target node of any dashed arc contains "(inline)".